# Combination of and or elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write query for following condition in elasticsearch

```
Select * from table1 where (cnd1 or cond2) and (cnd3)
```

My cond2 value is from nested object . My json object is below

```
details={ "name"="name1",
      "address":"{
      "city":"city1"
      }"
      }
```

I need to take city from above object

```
details.address.city
```

Is above syntax is right , if not how to get value of second object city.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : cond3,
            "should" : [
                cond1,
                cond2
            ],
            "minimum_should_match" : 1
        }

}
```

go through this link for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: Hi blackmamba, Thanks for your suggestion . Now i changed my question can you suggest for my changed query

Comment: can you give me your mapping ? what's the query you're trying now ?

Comment: you give me idea for the question i asked  , and one thing more is , for the cond2 i need to check value of city inside my nested object.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a conditional queries with Elasticsearch. But there is some weird situation of your data section.

```
details={ "name"="name1",
      "address":"{
      "city":"city1"
      }"
      }
```

Elasticsearh save your data as a json object, but you should give your data as a json. In this section, there is an object, you try to sent. Let us examine:

There is a name attribute of detail object, it is a string. And also there is a address attribute, and it is a string too. It should be an object which has to include a city attribute if you want to reach this object via `details.address.city`. Now we try to fix:

```
{
  "id":...,
  ...
  "details": {
    "name": "name1",
    "address": {
      "city": "city1"
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, I remove double quotation marks of details object. Now, you can reach city attribute of json as a json object. Now, we create a query to reach cities:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "your-json-attribute": "???"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "your-json-attribute": "???"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "your-json-attribute": "???"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I use `term` query but there is lots of another query types. You can check them on documentation. But for `And` and `Or`, you can use `bool` query. Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html