# how can get the data using elastic search when they are "AND-OR"conditions (Query builder)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

For example, if I had to fetch the Results from the text matching from all the fileds
"(userId   OR currentUserId) AND (customeromerId OR customercode OR customerbacth) AND (customerph or customer addrss ) AND customercity".

If I use the below code I am getting the results which are matched according to the keywords irrespective of `AND`  `OR` conditions.

```
 $queryMsg = ['query_string' => ['query' => $query]];
```

But I want to fetch the results, for example, a record which matches userId or currentUserId and customeromerId should be fetched.

Please help me out how to write a  query in elastic search so that I can fetch the results.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304478/combination-of-and-or-elasticsearch

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 1):

```
{
"query" : {
    "must" : [
        {
            "bool" : {
                "should" : [
                    {
                        "match" : {'userId' : id}

                    },
                    {
                        "match" : {'currentUserId' : id}
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match" : 1
            }
        },
        {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match": {'customeromerId': code}

                    },
                    {
                        "match": {'customercode': code}
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {'customerbacth': code}
                    }
                ],
            "minimum_should_match" : 1
            },
        },
        {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match": {'customerph': address}

                    },
                    {
                        "match": {'customer addrss': address}
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match" : 1
            }
        },
        {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : {
                    "customercity" : city
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: But i need to search all the data irrespective of the column name.like its should search all the fields ...like address should be searched in all the column name if it's present in the name also it should fetch that it.

Comment: Do you one input that you want to search in all columns or you have multiple inputs that you want to search in all columns?

Comment: one input to search all the columns.."(userId OR currentUserId) AND (customeromerId OR customer _code OR customer_batch) AND (customerphnumber or customer address ) AND customer_city" should search the data with or and condition. (sirisha or 123)and (g123 or code123 or maths).so i want to get the records with sirisha or 123 having g123 or code123 or maths.

Comment: id, code, address and city are variables, u can replace them as per your input